# Optimization problem on the inner product of two probability vectors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, convex-optimization

We are given a $d$-dimensional probability vector $\mathbf{p}$. Let $P$ be the set of products of the corresponding entries between $\mathbf{p}$ and another $d$-dimensional
probability vector $\mathbf{p}'$. Clearly, we have $\sum_{x\in P} x=\langle\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p}'\rangle$. Finally, let $s_k$ be the sum of smallest $k$ elements of $P$ for a given integer $0<k<d$, and let $s_k^*$ be the maximum value of $s_k$ over all probability vectors $\mathbf{p}'$.

---

**Question:** How can we express $s_k^*$ in terms of $\mathbf{p}$?

Comment: Intuitively, I would say that $s_k^*$ will be equal to maximum of the $k$ smallest elements of $p$ where $p'$ will be zero everywhere except at the index $i$ for which $p_i$ is that maximum of the $k$ smallest elements.

Comment: Thank you @KBS .  If $\mathbf{p}$ is $(5/12, 4/12, 2/12, 1/12)^{\top}$, for $k=2$ one gets $s_k^*=5/57$ with  $\mathbf{p'} = (4/19, 5/19, 10/19, 0)^{\top}$. For $k=2$ one gets $s_k^*=5/27$ with  $\mathbf{p'} = (4/9, 5/9, 0, 0)^{\top}$. Hence, it must be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via linear programming, as shown by the following derivation from a bilevel maximin optimization problem.  For a given $p'\in \mathbb{R}_+^d$ such that $\sum_i p'_i = 1$, let the inner problem be $$f(p') = \min_{x\in\{0,1\}^d: \sum_i x_i = k} p_i p'_i x_i.$$  The outer problem is to maximize $f(p')$.  By total unimodularity, we can relax integrality of $x$, so
$$f(p') = \min_{x\in[0,1]^d: \sum_i x_i = k} p_i p'_i x_i.$$
Now by LP duality, we have
$$f(p') = \max_{r\in\mathbb{R}, z\in\mathbb{R}_+^d: r - z_i \le p_i p'_i} \left(kr-\sum_i z_i\right).$$
Hence the problem of maximizing $f(p')$ is equivalent to maximizing
$$s_k = k r - \sum_i z_i \label1\tag1$$ subject to
\begin{align}
z_i &\ge r - p_i p'_i &&\text{for all $i$} \label2\tag2 \\
\sum_i p'_i &= 1 \label3\tag3 \\
p'_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \label4\tag4 \\
z_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \label5\tag5
\end{align}
You can interpret the variable $r$ as representing the $k$th smallest $p_i p'_i$ and the variable $z_i$ as representing $\max(r-p_i p'_i,0)$.

Without loss of generality, assume $0 < p_1 \le \dots \le p_d$.  Empirically, it appears that $$s^*_k = \max_{i \in\{0,\dots,k-1\}} \frac{k-i}{\sum_{j=i+1}^d \frac{1}{p_j}}.$$
This empirical formula was derived by considering solutions of the form $p'_i=0$ for small $i$ (possibly none) and $p_i p'_i$ constant after that.  As a step toward proving this, it might help to consider the dual LP problem for \eqref{1}-\eqref{5}, which can be written as minimizing $\max_i p_i \alpha_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i \alpha_i &= k \\
0 \le \alpha_i &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

Comment: I now rejected this answer because I realized that if $p_i=1/d$ for all $1\le i\le d$, then one obtains $s_k^*=(d-k)p_i^2$ with $p'_i=p_i$ for all $1\le i\le d$. Could you please correct your answer?

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati The LP was correct, but the formula for $s_k^*$ was not.  I have now corrected it.

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt . If $\textbf{p}$ is $(1/12, 2/12, 4/12, 5/12)^{\top}$, for $k=3$ one gets $s_k^*=5/27$ with $\textbf{p}'= (0, 0, 5/9, 4/9)$, while the largest $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $p_i < k/\sum_{j=1}^d \frac{1}{p_j}=5/39\sim 0.128$ is $i^*=1$ because $p_1=1/12 \sim 0.083<0.128$ and $p_2=2/12\sim 0.166>0.128$. Using your last formulas one gets $\frac{k-i^*}{\sum_{i=i^*+1}^d \frac{1}{p_i}}=10/27$ with $\textbf{p}'= (0, 20/19, 10/19, 8/19)$. Hence, there is some other mistake in your answer and I had to reject it again. Could you please correct it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati Sorry for the errors.  Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for extending your answer by providing additional details.